# Relation between Causality conditions and Energy conditions in Einstein's gravity

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, causality

It is known that a general solution for Einstein's field equations $G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=kT_{\mu\nu}$ may not be always physically realizable. Energy conditions put restrictions on these solutions by imposing the "positive energy density rule" on Stress-Energy tensor (RHS of the field equations). Causal conditions are more concerned with the geometry of space-time (LHS of field equations?) and aims at removing pathological solutions containing closed time-like curves (CTCs). Similar to energy conditions, there are a number of alternative causal conditions - like Globally hyperbolic, causally simple, distinguishing, chronological etc. They form a hierarchy of causality conditions - globally hyperbolic space-times are most restrictive while chronological is the least restrictive.

The purpose of causality and energy condition is to come up with physically realizable solutions for Einstein's field equations, but how are these conditions really related to one another? Does there exist one-to-one correspondence between certain type of energy condition and causality condition (say, Globally hyperbolic space-time implies weak energy condition for $T_{\mu\nu}$ or so)? I might be wrong but intuitively it appears as if the energy and causality conditions are just two sides of the same coin

Comment: There are a lot of theorems regarding this and usually they involved a mixture of causality conditions, energy conditions and the types of singularities on the spacetime.

Comment: Can you provide reference for these theorems? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Probably the most famous is the one from Tipler : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491677903487

Comment: To my knowledge there are no strong generic implications and results are established case by case. Also, energy conditions are about local properties, while causality conditions are about global properties.

Comment: "I might be wrong but intuitively it appears as if the energy and causality conditions are just two sides of the same coin" -> indeed, for matter they are: "Thermodynamic Stability Implies Causality" https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.128.010606

Comment: Thank you for the reference @Quillo